# Initiate function/event from child to parent

Tags: reactjs, components

In my parent component I have a function/event that looks like this:

```
const onClick = e => {
        e.preventDefault();
        POST('/api', { data: data }).then(
            async (response) => {
                const json = await response.json()
                setData(json.data)
            }
        )
    }
```

On the parent component, this is initiated by the following:

```
 <button type="button" onClick={onClick}>Click me</button>
```

However, I also have a child component, where I would like a click event in that to also initiate this function/event and a . How is that done ?

I tried just doing something like:

```
<ChildComponent onclick={onClick} data={data} setData={setData} />
```

And then in the child component just doing something like:

```
<div onClick={() => {props.setData(i); props.onClick;}}>
```

But that doesn't seem to work.

So any hints to what I'm doing wrong here ?

Comment: `<div onClick={() => {props.onClick;}}>` should be `<div onClick={props.onClick}>`

Comment: Okay, what if I am doing two events at the same time ? I am actually also using a `useState` at the same time. So I need to `setMyState` and call the function at the same time ?

Comment: In that case, you can define a function and pass the event `onClick={(event) => { props.onClick(event)
  // update state
}}`

Comment: My IDE tells me that event is deprecated ? :)

Comment: Can you add the error to the question?

Comment: I've actually tried this now: `onClick={(e) => {props.setData(i+1); props.onClick(e)}}`. And this semi works. But not as intended. It's like the first click initiates the first `props.setData`, and not the second. And then if I click again `props.onClick` is initiated.

Comment: Change `onclick` to `onClick` in the ChildComponent and change `props.onClick;` to `props.onClick();` to call it.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if this will fix your problem, but it seems you are using incorrectly the function prop.

Try this:

```
<div onClick={(e) => {props.setData(i); props.onClick(e);}}>
```

You can use functions in onClick in 2 ways:

1 - Assign the prop function itself to the onClick:

```
<div onClick={props.onClick}>
```

2 - Assign a callback to the onClick which calls the function with the event:

```
<div onClick={(e) => props.onClick(e)}>
```

To summarize: the onClick needs to receive a function, but your problem was you were assigning a callback (this is correct) which was not calling the props.onClick one

[you were doing props.onClick instead of props.onClick()]

You should update the state in the parent, not in the child. I am not sure why you are calling props.setData in the child when you can handle that in the parent onClick function.